# Independent HTTP status for each array element

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am using the following code to print some information in HTML.

I have problems.
First, I use:

```
fetch(resultado.url).then(function(response) {console.log(response.status);
```

To obtain the http status of the URL that is inside the array "channelList", but I don't know how to get that state independently, I mean, for all elements of the array.

And after that, if I change 'getElementbyID' to 'getElementbyClassName' to show 'status' in HTML, this doesn't work

```js
const channelList = [
{
    name: "La 1",
    title: "RTVE La 1",
    link: "go:la1",
    imgClass: "la1",
    flag: "es",
    url: "./la1.html",
},

{
    name: "La 2",
    title: "RTVE La 2",
    link: "go:la1",
    imgClass: "la1",
    flag: "es",
    url: "./la2.html",
},
];

const resultado = channelList.find( canal => canal.name === 'La 1' );

// HTTP STATUS

fetch(resultado.url).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.status);
    if(response.status !== 200){
        let stt = document.getElementById('hlstatus');
        stt.innerText = "Offline";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('hlstatus').innerText = "Online";
    }
});

// PRINT ON HTML

const container = document.getElementById("locales");

var img = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e";
channelList.forEach(result => {
  // Construct card content
const content = `
<div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
    <div class="dropdown card darkolorbg text-white card-canal card-link text-white">
        <a class="card-link text-white" href="${result.link}" ${result.dDown}>
        <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <img class="canal-img ${result.imgClass}" src="${img}" alt="">
        </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><h5>${result.name} <span class="hidden">${result.title}</span> <br><span class="subtf1"><i class="flag ${result.flag}"></i></span> <span id="hlstatus"></span> </div>
        </div>
        </a>
        </div>
</div>
    `;
  // Append newyly created card element to the container
container.innerHTML += content;
});
```

```html
<div id="locales"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this code should work as you expect.
But pay attention, please, to error processing.
It could be done by passing callback function to `.catch` method of the promise.

```js
var img = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e";
const container = document.getElementById("locales");

// PRINT ON HTML

function makeStatusCard(result) {
  const content = `
<div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
    ${result.status}
    <div class="dropdown card darkolorbg text-white card-canal card-link text-white">
        <a class="card-link text-white" href="${result.link}" ${result.dDown}>
        <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <img class="canal-img ${result.imgClass}" src="${img}" alt="">
        </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><h5>${result.name} <span class="hidden">${result.title}</span> <br><span class="subtf1"><i class="flag ${result.flag}"></i></span> <span id="hlstatus"></span> </div>
        </div>
        </a>
        </div>
</div>
    `;
  // Append newyly created card element to the container
container.innerHTML += content;
}

const channelList = [
{
    name: "La 1",
    title: "RTVE La 1",
    link: "go:la1",
    imgClass: "la1",
    flag: "es",
    url: "https://avax.dev/data/validators.json",
},

{
    name: "La 2",
    title: "RTVE La 2",
    link: "go:la1",
    imgClass: "la1",
    flag: "es",
    url: "https://avax.dev/data/validators.json",
},
];

// HTTP STATUS

for (let channel of channelList) {
   fetch(channel.url).then(function(response) {
      channel.status = response.status === 200 ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
      makeStatusCard(channel);
   });
}
```

```html
<div id="locales"></div>
```